# Is it possible to use the same slice notation in both a list and an element to get the same result?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, slice

I want to get the element in the last index of a list, but sometimes the last index is a list, in this case I want the first element in the nested list.

```
#list in moment 1:
Lm1 = [1,2,3,4]

#list in moment 2:
Lm2 = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3]]
```

I can just use an if for this.

```
#Option1:

def if_list(lastposition):
    if isinstance(lastposition, list):
        return list[0]
    else:
        return lastposition

element = if_list(Lm1[-1])
do whatever
```

Or if I want to do the same operation in both cases I could buit the list like this and use the same slice notation. It will give the element I want.

```
#Option2:

Lm1 = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
Lm2 = [[1],[2],[3],[4],[1,2,3]]

Lm1[-1][0]
Lm2[-1][0]
```

Is there a way to do this using something similar to slice notation that will work in both cases (when index is list and when index is not list) or a simple one liner?

Something like:

```
#Lm1[-1:][:]...
```

The problem is that I don't know if its more time eficient to just build the list 
 like Option2 and use the same slice notation or to use the if cause everytime like Option1.

I'm using pythom 3.7, don't know much about older versions.

Comment: Or a Try Except maybe?

Comment: "Is there a way to do this using something similar to slice notation that will work in both cases" no, there isn't. In general, it is sign of a problem in your design if your list contains heterogenous data types like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a test bench to compare using try-except and isinstance to see which is faster and here are the results.

Option2:
Parsing all data to a list doesn't seem like an efficient way to me. :/

```
import time, statistics 

Lm2 = [1,2,3,4,1,2,3]
t = []
for y in range(4):
    s = time.time()
    for i in range(100000):
        if isinstance(Lm2[-1], list):
            x =  Lm2[-1][0]
        else:
            x = Lm2[-1]
    t.append(time.time() - s)
print(statistics.mean(t))

Lm2 = [1,2,3,[4,1,2,3]]
t = []
for y in range(4):
    s = time.time()
    for i in range(100000):
        try:
            x =  Lm2[-1][0]
        except Exception:
            x = Lm2[-1]
    t.append(time.time() - s)
print(statistics.mean(t))

Lm2 = [1,2,3,[4,1,2,3]]
t = []
for y in range(4):
    s = time.time()
    for i in range(100000):
        x = Lm2[-1][0] if type(Lm2[-1]) is list else Lm2[-1]
    t.append(time.time() - s)
print(statistics.mean(t))
```

The results as follow in order

```
# When the last element is a list 
# 0.024208366870880127
# 0.011709034442901611
# 0.03266298770904541

# When the last element is an int 
# 0.02896404266357422
# 0.015629112720489502
# 0.03452497720718384
```

According to the data I got, using try-except will be always faster

Comment: Thanks for that. I was having trouble to time the execution because I was using timeit.timeit, I gave a look at your code to learn how to do it. Do you think there is a problem in catching the 'TypeError' exception? Is it possible to catch the same error from an unexpected cause? I looked the python docs to see the cases slicings raises erros and couldn't find. [link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/exceptions.html#TypeError) [link](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#slicings)

Comment: You're absolutely right, catching TypeError is the better way of doing it, if you go to my answer's history you will see me using it but I've changed for simplicity while testing but forgot to revert it back. The general exception should be the last as you might face different error types. @ThiagoLuiz

Answer (score 0):

You can do a one liner like this if you want:

```
#list in moment 1:
Lm1 = [1,2,3,4]

#list in moment 2:
Lm2 = [1,2,3,4,[1,2,3]]

def test(test_list):
    return test_list[-1][0] if type(test_list[-1]) is list else test_list[-1]

print(test(Lm1))
print(test(Lm2))
```

Check if the last value is a list, if it is, return the first value, otherwise give you the last element of your list.